# Adjust image quality before upload

Tags: javascript, image, upload

I'm trying to downsize an image quality before it is sent to the PHP script and uploaded.
Is this possible?
If so would I be able to do it in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could probably done with the new HTML5 file APIs, but this isn't supported by all browsers (far from it). Using PHP after the upload is the only real way here.

If you want to try doing it with HTML5:

- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications
- http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Comment: How would PHP be able to downsize the image before upload?

Comment: It wouldn't. What I meant is you can downsize it after the upload with PHP.

Comment: I already have it doing that :( Where would I go to find the HTML 5 solution?

Comment: You'll need to write it yourself. I'd look into the file API, load a file, resize it inside a canvas, then upload the canvas to PHP. I've edited my original post with a few links.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible by using the new Javascript function introduced with HTML5, but as HTML5 isn't supported by every browser and it's still under development, there is no way you can do this by using Javascript.

A Java applet could be an option if you can rely on a installed Java runtime on your customers client (intranet, etc.)